# SL4A Python SMS Date Format

Tags: python, date, sms, sl4a

I am accessing my SMS messages with:

```
ms=droid.smsGetMessages(False, 'inbox', ['date']).result
```

The results are in the following format:

```
[{u'date': u'1416143072400'}]
```

How do I convert the date value to a readable format (dd/mm/yyyy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting back seconds since the epoch times 1000..

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(u'1416143072400')//1000)
datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 16, 14, 4, 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x you can do

```
import datetime

ms = [{u'date': u'1416143072400'}]

timestamp = int(ms[0]['date'])/1000

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

# 16/11/2014
```

but I don't know whether `datetime` is available in SL4A